# Run Java Code after a SOAP web service response generated

Tags: java, web-services

I have webservice which calls mail service before sending response. I wanted to send mail service after returning response.
Problem is now that if mail service mails my transaction also fails because response is not generated.
Response should generated regardless mail service execute success or not.
Please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use a message queue do asynchronously send emails. Your web service should just put an entry to the queue and send the response back to the caller without waiting for the email sending.

Email must be sent by a service which will poll the queue and send the email.